# $(window).scroll being executed inside if-statement even when it doesn't meet the conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a [debounce script](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize) as part of a conditional that will add some css to a side menu when a user scrolls a page beyond a certain amount of pixels and then hide the menu when they are a set amount of pixels from the bottom. The script works as intended for screen widths 992px and above (as per conditional `if (debounce_bodyWidth >= 992)`) but it is still executing for dimensions below this.

Is there something about `$(window).scroll` that means it is executed irrespective of conditionals?

```
(function ($) {
    contactDebounce = function () {
        var debounce_bodyWidth = $(window).width();
        if (debounce_bodyWidth >= 992) {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                var distanceFromBottom = $(document).height() - $(this).scrollTop();

                if (distanceFromBottom <= 1200) {
                    $('.sticky-element').addClass('hide');
                } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 150) {
                    $('.sticky-element').removeClass('hide');
                    $('.sticky-element').css({
                        'position': 'fixed',
                        'top': '15px'
                    });
                } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < 150) {
                    $('.sticky-element').css({
                        'position': 'relative',
                        'top': '0'
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
    contactDebounce();
    $(window).on("debouncedresize", contactDebounce);
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: you are binding the scroll event everytime your window is greater than 992, so if you go to more than 992 then it will be bound (and fire) even when you go smaller than 992.  You want to probably bind it once and then put the if condition inside the event

Comment: If you'd [debugged this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code) you would of likely been able to discover this easily yourself.

Comment: Cheers Pete. Now that I look at it I see that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is binding a function to `$(window).scroll` on page load if the `bodyWidth >= 992`, <s>this condition is never run again as all that is run on scroll is inside the scroll function you have created.</s>

EDIT: It has been pointed out in comments that this is run again, on debounced resize. The problem then is that the scroll function has already been set when the condition is true and is not unset when the condition becomes false. You can either unset the event and check again on resize or add the condition inside the event and stop running the check on resize.

Try this, adding the condition inside the event:

```
(function ($) {
    contactDebounce = function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {

            var debounce_bodyWidth = $(window).width();
            if (debounce_bodyWidth >= 992) {
                var distanceFromBottom = $(document).height() - $(this).scrollTop();
                var stickyElement = $('.sticky-element');

                if (distanceFromBottom <= 1200) {
                    stickyElement.addClass('hide');
                } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 150) {
                    stickyElement.removeClass('hide');
                    stickyElement.css({
                        'position': 'fixed',
                        'top': '15px'
                    });
                } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < 150) {
                    stickyElement.css({
                        'position': 'relative',
                        'top': '0'
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    contactDebounce();
})(jQuery);
```

Or this, unbind when smaller, rebind when bigger:

```
(function ($) {
    contactDebounce = function () {
        var debounce_bodyWidth = $(window).width();
        if (debounce_bodyWidth >= 992) {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                var distanceFromBottom = $(document).height() - $(this).scrollTop();
                var stickyElement = $('.sticky-element');
                if (distanceFromBottom <= 1200) {
                    stickyElement.addClass('hide');
                } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 150) {
                    stickyElement.removeClass('hide');
                    stickyElement.css({
                        'position': 'fixed',
                        'top': '15px'
                    });
                } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < 150) {
                    stickyElement.css({
                        'position': 'relative',
                        'top': '0'
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $(window).unbind('scroll');
        }
    }

    contactDebounce();
    $(window).on("debouncedresize", contactDebounce);
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Edited out the duplicate jQuery selector. It's a good practice to avoid unnecessary DOM traversing.

Comment: Agreed, I had just looked at the problem, missed that. Thanks

Comment: I was too slow to point out the things you said, so I just wanted to be at least a bit helpful ;)

Comment: "this condition is never run again" - it's run at startup and on every `$(window).debouncedresize()" - see @Pete 's comment on the OP.

Comment: Yeah, that's the answer and it now makes perfect sense. Cheers to everyone (apart form Liam :P)